# How do I render duplicate classes using the amerpsand operator in scss?

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to generate a double class using scss for [specifity reasons](https://csswizardry.com/2014/07/hacks-for-dealing-with-specificity/#safely-increasing-specificity) and avoiding the usage of the dreaded `!important`

I have tried the following example:

```
.my-class {
  color: black;

  &.&:hover {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

But all I'm getting is:

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "... of parent rule": expected "}", was "&.&:hover {"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reference to [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45658473/3162554), the ampersand can be interpolated as well:

```
.my-class {
  color: black;

  &#{&}:hover {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

outputs

```
.my-class {
  color: black;
}
.my-class.my-class:hover {
  color: red;
}
```